# How to get .ipa file path

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipa

My application contains sensitive data so I want to generate hash key for .ipa file, is it possible to do? how to get .ipa file path to generate key.

I already did it few files for inside .app file.

Comment: I feel your question a bit senseless... you should encrypt your _sensitive_ data programmatically if you are afraid of someone has un-athorised access to those, bypassing the application.

Comment: @holex, yes your right. But mine is bank application so we want take layered security approach. I am already did for inside the .app file what and all i want. In this point any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In iPhone

If your using install0us the location is

**`/var/Mobile/Library/Downloads/`**

If your transferring purchases via iTunes, no ipa files get copied onto the iPhone, they are installed into `**/Applications/ or /var/mobile/Library/Applications in the form of "Application.app"**`.

also, the .ipa Files Location in Mac OS

```
1- Launch iTunes
2- Under Library menu, click on [Apps] menu.
3- The iTunes will display all installed app
4- Right-click on one of those apps
5- Then click “Show in Finder” option
Alternative way to do that is, by simply open the directory of .ipa files stored by using this path:
User/Music/iTunes/Mobile Applications
```

Comment: as of now i did it like this for provision file :                         NSString *certificatePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                                 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"embedded.mobileprovision"];

Comment: you'll get .app path from NSString *certificatePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] excutablePath];

Comment: This approach may not work now starting from iTunes 12.7.0.
Instead, you can use [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12).
You have to plug your phone to Mac using USB cable, and then navigate to this path:

**`~/Library/Group Containers/K36BKF7T3D.group.com.apple.configurator/Library/Caches/Assets/TemporaryItems/MobileApps/`**

Answer (score 3):

**The .ipa Files Location in Windows**

```
 - Launch iTunes
 - Under Library menu, click on [Apps] menu.
 - The iTunes will display all installed app
 - Right-click on one of those apps
 - Then click “Show in Windows Explorer” option
 - A Windows Explorer will be opened navigating directly to the path of .ipa files.
```

**Alternatively,**

```
 you can simply open a Windows Explorer and type this path in the address bar: C:\Users\User\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Mobile Applications`
```

**The .ipa Files Location in Mac OS**

```
 -  Launch iTunes
 -  Under Library menu, click on [Apps] menu.
 -  The iTunes will display all installed app
 -  Right-click on one of those apps
 -  Then click “Show in Finder” option
```

**Alternative**

```
way to do that is, by simply open the directory of .ipa files stored by using this path: User/Music/iTunes/Mobile Applications
```

[Reference](http://www.driversoftwaretips.com/2013/04/how-to-find-iphone-apps-ipa-files-on.html)